# How to create org charts in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

How to create org charts in vb.net?

Comment: Instead of making an org chart from scratch, you may use a premade one. You just type your organization data, select reporting line layout and click the button. In order to get more idea, you may check out https://www.someka.net/excel-template/advanced-automatic-organizational-chart-generator/

Answer (score 1):

Draw your own, using boxes and lines in the graphics paint method?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visio, then you could use Automation to create an org chart in Visio.

Answer (score 0):

Get a copy of Microsoft Office and fire up Visio.  Drag and drop to your heart's content. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Presumably the OP wants to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at our component mentioned in the link above :

demos @  http://www.orgchartcomponent.com/demo.aspx and download the samples from else where on the site!

Comment: So this is your product?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the TreeView control.

It has several limitations for writing an org chart (no way to do double reporting or matrix 
organizations), but if the org you want to represent is hierarchical, it is OK.

It does not require any type of extension like Visio or creating your own graphics: this is the main reason for which I used it in my application.

Draw appropriate icons to represente the various level of organization and do extensive use of tooltips to make it more usable. It can be easily put in a SQL DB.

Main source for information with several good examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview(v=VS.100).aspx